# MySQL order by priority

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hi I'm building a Java program, where i need to manage some items. In order to do that I need to filter the items. I filter items by building SQL query and executing it. I need the following query to first sort 
(`LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM grupe ORDER BY grupe.pavadinimas DESC)grupe ON`)
 AND only then add all the other data and execute WHERE clause.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
      (
        SELECT  preke.* 
        FROM    preke_tiekejas
                , preke 
        WHERE   preke_tiekejas.tiek_id IN (18610,13604) 
                AND preke.pr_id=preke_tiekejas.pr_id 
        GROUP BY 
                preke_tiekejas.pr_id
      ) preke
      , preke_kaina
      , (
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    preke_info 
        WHERE   preke_info.pavadinimas LIKE '%kait%'
      ) preke_info
    ) LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT  * 
      FROM    grupe 
      ORDER BY 
              grupe.pavadinimas DESC
    )grupe ON grupe.pgs_id=preke.pgs_id 
    LEFT JOIN gamintojas ON gamintojas.gam_id=preke.gam_id 
    LEFT JOIN grupe_darb ON grupe_darb.pgs_id=grupe.pgs_id 
WHERE   preke_kaina.pr_id=preke.pr_id 
    AND preke_info.pr_id=preke.pr_id 
    AND grupe_darb.darb_id = 20 
LIMIT 0, 500
```

If I remove these two subqueries :

```
(SELECT * FROM preke_info WHERE preke_info.pavadinimas LIKE '%kait%')

(SELECT preke.* FROM preke_tiekejas, preke
WHERE preke_tiekejas.tiek_id IN (18610,13604)
AND preke.pr_id=preke_tiekejas.pr_id
GROUP BY preke_tiekejas.pr_id)
```

then the query works the way I want.

**P.S.** order it only in the end of the query is not an option, because there is huge amount of records and then it becomes slow as hell.

**Explain**

[image]

**@Lieven**:

queries results are **NOT** same - without limit should be ~90k rows:
[image]

queries results are **NOT** same - return ~50rows:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to read your query, I would reformat it to this

**Reformatted**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
          (
            SELECT  preke.* 
            FROM    preke_tiekejas
                    , preke 
            WHERE   preke_tiekejas.tiek_id IN (18610,13604) 
                    AND preke.pr_id=preke_tiekejas.pr_id 
            GROUP BY 
                    preke_tiekejas.pr_id
          ) preke
          , preke_kaina
          , (
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    preke_info 
            WHERE   preke_info.pavadinimas LIKE '%kait%'
          ) preke_info
        ) LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT  * 
          FROM    grupe 
          ORDER BY 
                  grupe.pavadinimas DESC
        )grupe ON grupe.pgs_id=preke.pgs_id 
        LEFT JOIN gamintojas ON gamintojas.gam_id=preke.gam_id 
        LEFT JOIN grupe_darb ON grupe_darb.pgs_id=grupe.pgs_id 
WHERE   preke_kaina.pr_id=preke.pr_id 
        AND preke_info.pr_id=preke.pr_id 
        AND grupe_darb.darb_id = 20 
LIMIT 0, 500
```

After reformatting, I would remove the implicit `JOIN` syntax. You should always try to use explicit `JOIN`'s for readability and maintainability. The implicit `JOIN` syntax will sooner or later become obsolete.

**Using explicit JOINS**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    ( (
            SELECT  preke.* 
            FROM    preke_tiekejas
                    INNER JOIN preke ON preke.pr_id=preke_tiekejas.pr_id 
            WHERE   preke_tiekejas.tiek_id IN (18610,13604)                     
            GROUP BY 
                    preke_tiekejas.pr_id
          ) preke
          INNER JOIN preke_kaina preke_kaina.pr_id=preke.pr_id 
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    preke_info 
            WHERE   preke_info.pavadinimas LIKE '%kait%'
          ) preke_info ON preke_info.pr_id=preke.pr_id 
        ) LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT  * 
          FROM    grupe 
          ORDER BY 
                  grupe.pavadinimas DESC
        )grupe ON grupe.pgs_id=preke.pgs_id 
        LEFT JOIN gamintojas ON gamintojas.gam_id=preke.gam_id 
        LEFT JOIN grupe_darb ON grupe_darb.pgs_id=grupe.pgs_id 
WHERE   grupe_darb.darb_id = 20 
LIMIT   0, 500
```

Now the redundant subqueries stand out. I might be off but I believe your statement can be further reduced to this

**Removing redundant subqueries**

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
          SELECT  preke.* 
          FROM    preke_tiekejas
                  INNER JOIN preke ON preke.pr_id=preke_tiekejas.pr_id 
          WHERE   preke_tiekejas.tiek_id IN (18610,13604)                     
          GROUP BY 
                  preke_tiekejas.pr_id
        ) preke
        INNER JOIN preke_kaina preke_kaina.pr_id=preke.pr_id 
        INNER JOIN preke_info ON preke_info.pr_id=preke.pr_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN grupe ON grupe.pgs_id=preke.pgs_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN gamintojas ON gamintojas.gam_id=preke.gam_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN grupe_darb ON grupe_darb.pgs_id=grupe.pgs_id 
WHERE   grupe_darb.darb_id = 20 
        AND preke_info.pavadinimas LIKE '%kait%'
ORDER BY 
        grupe.pavadinimas DESC
LIMIT   0, 500
```

Now, to me, this is a query I can work with. Unfortunatly, I don't see any glaring performance problems with it that proper indexing can't solve.

Can you show us the execution plan for your query?

Comment: If i understand correctly, this is what you wanted: http://i44.tinypic.com/ibl64i.jpg

Comment: @Minutis - Yes. I have added it to your question. Can you verify if my revised statement delivers the same results as your original query does?

Comment: @Minutis - Now I am a layman when it comes to reading MySQL Explain plans but it looks to me like you are missing an index on `grupe_darb`.

Comment: Ok the result from your 3rd query is the same, and the speed is twice as good as my query. BUT if I remove first two search subqueries (`AND preke_info.pavadinimas LIKE '%kait%'` and `(
          SELECT  preke.* 
          FROM    preke_tiekejas
                  INNER JOIN preke ON preke.pr_id=preke_tiekejas.pr_id 
          WHERE   preke_tiekejas.tiek_id IN (18610,13604)                     
          GROUP BY 
                  preke_tiekejas.pr_id
        )`) your query takes 69 seconds to execute and mine takes only 0,3second.

Comment: Yes, there is no index, should I add a composite primary key?

Comment: After adding composite key, your 3rd query reduced to 4 seconds, still my query executes at ~0,4second.

Comment: @Minutis - You seem to be getting there all by yourself <g>. Can you post a revised execution plan after adding the composite key.

Comment: I'm getting there not without your help. But remember, that real problem starts, when you remove those two subqueries I mentioned in my second comment (without them there is like 90k rows of data and this is only start it will increase to 1kk+). The timing is my priority here. New plan: http://i40.tinypic.com/wirbz6.jpg

Comment: @Minutis - Do you really need a `select *` from `preke` table? Further optimizations might be possible here. What about the outer `select *`? Do you mean that your query *with* the subselects executes in 0,4 seconds?

Comment: I'll update my post to show execute times of both, mine and your queries.

Comment: My mistake, after looking more into it, the results are not the same. Your results are correct and mine are not. But maybe there is any way to increase speed of your query to like 1 second or so, because I am afraid, that when there is like 1kk records, there might be big pauses between even paging with LIMIT statement.

Comment: @Minutis - This question will not attract many new people. I would suggest you to ask about optimizing the final query in a seperate question, perhaps linking to this one if some background is needed.